# How to change a django QueryDict to Python Dict?

Tags: python, django

Let's pretend I have the following QueryDict:

```
<QueryDict: {u'num': [0], u'var1': [u'value1', u'value2'], u'var2': [u'8']}>
```

I'd like to have a dictionary out of this, eg:

```
{'num': [0], 'var1':['value1', 'value2'], 'var2':['8']}
```

(I don't care if the unicode symbol `u` stays or goes.)

If I do `queryDict.dict()`, as suggested by the [django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict), I lose the extra values belonging to `var1`, eg:

```
{'num': [0], 'var1':['value2'], 'var2':['8']}
```

I was thinking of doing this:

```
myDict = {}
for key in queryDict.iterkeys():
    myDict[key] = queryDict.getlist(key)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This should work: `myDict = dict(queryDict.iterlists())`

Comment: queryDict.iterlists() is making a list value from each key, maybe because you spect lists?, queryDict.iteritems() if you know that querydict does not contains list.

Comment: In django 1.6: dict(data._iteritems())

Comment: In Django 1.6, `dict(queryDict.lists())` seems to work

Comment: In Django 1.8 on Python 3 all I needed was `dict(queryDict)`.

Comment: This doesnt work for many libraries including authomatic. See my question and my own answer here (works with v2 and v3 of python): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026535/authomatic-request-is-deprecated-the-returned-state-doesnt-match-with-the-st

Comment: QueryDict.dict() will convert QueryDict into a flat list

Comment: Works for django 1.5

Comment: Does not work for Django >= 2.0. Use ```QueryDict.dict()``` instead.

Comment: Djano3.2 and Python3.7, I used ```queryDict.dict() ``` is working fine.

Answer (score 253):

New in Django >= 1.4.

`QueryDict.dict()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict

Comment: Two ways to find out, try it, or view the source. The answer is no:
    def dict(self):
        """
        Returns current object as a dict with singular values.
        """
        return dict((key, self[key]) for key in self)

Comment: While this solves the problem for some of the people who come to this page from google, it doesn't answer OP's question which explicitly asks for retaining multiple values for a key.

Comment: Working on Django 1.11

Comment: To keep all the elements a key can contains, it could be better to use `QueryDict.list()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists that keeps all the elements. Then, we can cast the list of tuples obtained into a dictionary.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I've ended up using:

```
def qdict_to_dict(qdict):
    """Convert a Django QueryDict to a Python dict.

    Single-value fields are put in directly, and for multi-value fields, a list
    of all values is stored at the field's key.

    """
    return {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in qdict.lists()}
```

From my usage this seems to get you a list you can send back to e.g. a form constructor.

**EDIT:** maybe this isn't the best method. It seems if you want to e.g. write `QueryDict` to a file for whatever crazy reason, `QueryDict.urlencode()` is the way to go. To reconstruct the `QueryDict` you simply do `QueryDict(urlencoded_data)`.

Comment: This method suffers from indeterminate behaviour; in a situation where a given key may have one or more values, you could sometimes get a string, and sometimes get a list of strings.

Answer (score 11):

just simply add

`queryDict=dict(request.GET)`
or `queryDict=dict(QueryDict)`

In your view and data will be saved in querDict as python Dict.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want the values as Arrays you can do the following:

```
# request = <QueryDict: {u'key': [u'123ABC']}>
dict(zip(request.GET.keys(), request.GET.values()))
{u'key': u"123ABC" }

# Only work for single item lists
# request = <QueryDict: {u'key': [u'123ABC',U 'CDEF']}>
dict(zip(request.GET.keys(), request.GET.values()))
{u'key': u"CDEF" }
```

zip is a powerful tool read more about it here http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: I know this is almost 6 years old, just pointing out for whoever reaches this answer: In Django >= 2.0 (might work in older versions as well, that's just the one I'm using), you can do `QueryDict.dict()` (i.e. `request.POST.dict()`) and it will return the values properly.

Comment: Luca you are a legend. This has been driving me mad all day! Yours is the only answer I can get to work.

Comment: Luca, this is a great answer!  Works great in django 3.1.  I was building this dictionary the hard way, appending keys/values but this does in one line.

Comment: Note: this does NOT work for multiple values (such as you'd get from a MultiSelectField). If your QueryDict has a key/value pair like this: `<QueryDict: {'names': ['Joe', 'Matt', 'Jean']}>`, then the `.dict()` method will return `{'names': 'Jean'}` instead of `{'names': ['Joe', 'Matt', 'Jean']}`

Answer (score 7):

```
from django.utils import six 
post_dict = dict(six.iterlists(request.POST))
```

Comment: There is no information or link to documentation. An answer should not be only code.

Answer (score 5):

With `Django 2.2` there are few clean solutions:

1. `QueryDict.dict()` is simplest but it will break `QueryDict` with lists as values, e.g:

```py
from django.http.request import QueryDict, MultiValueDict

query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
query_dict.update(MultiValueDict({'a': ['one', 'two']}))
query_dict.update({'b': 'three'})

for key, value in query_dict.dict().items():  # ---> query_dict.dict()
    print(key, value)
```

will output

```
a two  # <--- missed 'one'
b three
```

2. `dict(QueryDict)` is better because it will make correct dictionary of lists:

```py
from django.http.request import QueryDict, MultiValueDict

query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
query_dict.update(MultiValueDict({'a': ['one', 'two']}))
query_dict.update({'b': 'three'})

for key, value in dict(query_dict).items():  # ---> dict(query_dict)
    print(key, value)
```

will output

```
a ['one', 'two']
b ['three']
```

which is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem, wanting to save arbitrary values from a form as serialized values.

My answer avoids explicitly iterating the dictionary contents: `dict(querydict.iterlists())`

In order to retrieve a dictionary-like value that functions as the original, an inverse function uses `QueryDict.setlist()` to populate a new `QueryDict` value.  In this case, I don't think the explicit iteration is avoidable.

My helper functions look like this:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

def querydict_dict(querydict):
    """
    Converts a Django QueryDict value to a regular dictionary, preserving multiple items.
    """
    return dict(querydict.iterlists())

def dict_querydict(dict_):
    """
    Converts a value created by querydict_dict back into a Django QueryDict value.
    """
    q = QueryDict("", mutable=True)
    for k, v in dict_.iteritems():
        q.setlist(k, v)
    q._mutable = False
    return q
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

```
myDict = dict(queryDict._iterlists())
```

Please Note : underscore `_` in iterlists method of `queryDict`. Django version :1.5.1

Answer (score 3):

`dict(request.POST)` returns a weird python dictionary with array wrapped values.

```
{'start': ['2017-01-14T21:00'], 'stop': ['2017-01-14T22:00'], 'email': ['sandeep@sakethtech.com']}
```

where as `{x:request.POST.get(x) for x in request.POST.keys()}` returns expected output.

```
{'start': '2017-01-14T21:00', 'stop': '2017-01-14T22:00', 'email': 'sandeep@sakethtech.com'}
```

Comment: In Django >= 2.0 (might work in older versions as well, that's just the one I'm using), you can do `QueryDict.dict()` (i.e. `request.POST.dict()`) and it will return the values properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved that problem:

```
dict_ = {k: q.getlist(k) if len(q.getlist(k))>1 else v for k, v in q.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried out both `dict(request.POST)` and `request.POST.dict()` and realised that if you have `list` values for example `'var1':['value1', 'value2']` nested in your `request.POST`, the later(`request.POST.dict()`) only gave me access to the last item in a nested list while the former(`dict(request.POST)`) allowed me to access all items in a nested list.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Like me, you probably are more familiar with `Dict()` methods in python. However, the `QueryDict()` is also an easy object to use. For example, perhaps you wanted to get the value from the `request.GET QueryDict()`.

You can do this like so: `request.GET.__getitem__(<key>)`.

`QueryDict()` documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Comment: Avoid using the double-underscore methods.  The more pythonic way would be to use `request.GET.get(<key>)` or `request.GET.getlist(<key>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple trick just

```
queryDict._mutable = False
# Change queryDict
your_dict = {'num': [0], 'var1':['value1', 'value2'], 'var2':['8']}
queryDict.upate(your_dict)
# reset the state
queryDict._mutable = True
```

I think this will help you better:
[This QueryDict instance is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717442/this-querydict-instance-is-immutable/#51196932)

Answer (score 0):

```
    user_obj = get_object_or_404(NewUser,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        queryDict = request.POST
        data = dict(queryDict)
        print(data['user_permissions[]'])
        user_obj.user_permissions.clear()
        user_obj.user_permissions.set(data['user_permissions[]'])
        return HttpResponse('Done')
```