# Reading Json in python (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm using Django for my webapp. I'm sending a JSON data to my views but I'm not able to access Nodes and edges by calling `decoded_data['nodes']` and it gives me :

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

error message.

Here is how I send json to to my view:

```
var a={
            nodes:   thisGraph.nodes,
            edges: saveEdges
        };

    //send data to server
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function change(){
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/",
        data: {'data': JSON.stringify(a)},
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(){
        console.log("Ajax worked");
        $('#message').text("Ajax worked");
        },
        headers:{'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
    });
```

---

here is my view:

```
data = request.POST.get("data")
json_encoded = json.dumps(data) 
decoded_data = json.loads(json_encoded)
logger.error(decoded_data['nodes'])
```

the decoded_data looks like this:

```
{"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x":658,"y":100},{"type":"
constraint","id":2,"title":"new Constraint","x":371,"y":95}],"edges":[{"source":
2,"target":0}]}
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: How does data look like? I tried running your code here with `data={"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x":658,"y":100},{"type":" constraint","id":2,"title":"new Constraint","x":371,"y":95}],"edges":[{"source": 2,"target":0}]}` and there are no errors

Comment: Yes it works when I do what did but when I get it from POST.get("data") it doesn't work. request.POST looks like this: <QueryDict: {'data': ['{"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x"
:658,"y":100},{"type":"node","id":2,"title":"new Node","x":356,"y":85}],"edges":
[{"source":2,"target":0}]}']}>

Comment: Does it really change between ' and "? How did you print this? `print data`?

Comment: Try this `myDict = dict(data.iterlists())` and see what happens (It seems like you have a QueryDict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349573/how-to-change-a-django-querydict-to-python-dict )

Comment: no it doesn't, I tried both. I used logger.error(request.POST)

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterlists'

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Try `decoded_data = json.loads(data[0])`

Comment: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. It seems i need json_encoded = json.dumps(data) others it keeps saying the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Then try `decoded_data = json.loads(decoded_data[0])`

Comment: I think you meant `decoded_data = json.loads(json_encoded[0])` I did that it says `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: No, realy try
`data = request.POST.get("data")
json_encoded = json.dumps(data) 
decoded_data = json.loads(json_encoded)
decoded_data = json.loads(decoded_data[0])`
And if it doesn't work print data for me.

Comment: Same thing 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: And can you print the value of `data`?

Comment: This is what i get from `request.post.get("data")`: `{"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x":658,"y":100},{"type":"
node","id":2,"title":"new Node","x":334,"y":60}],"edges":[{"source":2,"target":0
}]}`.  Isn't there something wrong in my ajax call?

Comment: Can you print `data.__class__`?

Comment: it says <class 'str'>

Comment: 'NoneType' is the type of None and should appear if a variable was not correctly set, or if it was set as `my_variable = None`.
if data is a string equal to this: `{"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x":658,"y":100},{"type":" node","id":2,"title":"new Node","x":334,"y":60}],"edges":[{"source":2,"target":0 }]}` then `decoded_data = json.loads(data)` should work

Comment: If that is not working by some reason try `data = request.POST.get("data") json_encoded = json.dumps(data) decoded_data = json.loads(json_encoded) decoded_data = json.loads(decoded_data)` or `request.POST.get("data") decoded_data = json.loads(str(data))`

Comment: when i use json.loads(str(data)) it gives me `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` and the other one gives me `the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'NoneType' is the type of `None` (Equivalent to Null in python) and should only appear if a variable was not correctly set, or if it was set as `my_variable = None`.

If data is a string equal to this:

```
data = '{"nodes":[{"type":"node","title":"new concept","id":0,"x":658,"y":100},{"type":" node","id":2,"title":"new Node","x":334,"y":60}],"edges":[{"source":2,"target":0 }]}'
```

Then simply using the following code should work:

```
decoded_data = json.loads(data)
```

Check if your requests are really coming from the AJAX request or if `data == None` like this:

```
data = request.POST.get("data")
if data === None:
    return "Error: not correctly formed request"
else:
    decoded_data = json.loads(data)
    nodes = decoded_data["nodes"]
    edges = decoded_data["edges"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
data = request.POST.get("data")
try:
    decoded_data = json.loads(data)
    nodes = decoded_data.get("nodes")
except:
    print("ERROR decoding")
```

request.POST.get("data") is a string. Just load it from there.

Comment: it says ERROR decoding

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I was using this code in my "/" url and the first time this code was getting called data was Null so I had to check if the call was AJAX and use this code in that condition.