# How to dump request.POST to dict, maintaining multiple value fields?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I want to store `ModelForm` data in database, in `JSONField`, to be able to create object from this data later, simply calling:

```
form = ModelForm(data_from_jsonfield_as_querydict)
if form.is_valid():
    object = form.save()
```

**Problem 1:**

I have data in POST:

```
>>> print request.POST
{u'field-1': u'value1', u'field-2': [u'value-2a', u'value-2b']}
```

And I have to convert this `QueryDict` to `dict`. But if I call `request.POST.dict()` I lose list values form field-2:

```
>>> print request.POST.dict()
{'field-1': 'value1', 'field-2': 'value-2b'}
```

I tried to use `request.POST.getlist` but then I obtain all values as a lists:

```
>>> for k in request.POST.keys():
...     print request.POST.getlist(k)
[u'value1']
[u'value-2a', u'value-2b']
```

I cannot even check if given value in above loop is list instance, because `request.POST.get(k)` does not return error if the value is list and on the other hand `request.POST[k]` returns `MultiValueDictKeyError` for every field.

The only solution which comes to my mind is to loop over all fields obtained by `getlist()` and convert one-value lists to strings, but it seems to me like overkill.

**Problem 2:**

Assuming the Problem 1 is resolved and I have `dict` with form data stored in database, like so:

```
# object.data
{u'field-1': u'value1', u'field-2': [u'value-2a', u'value-2b']}
```

When I want to create object using above `dict` as form data, I have to convert it do `QueryDict`, which can be simply done by:

```
querydict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
querydict.update(object.data)
```

And then:

```
form = ModelForm(querydict)
```

The problem is that when creating `querydict` from `dict` with some values which are list instance, all `querydict` values are wrapped in lists:

```
print querydict
{u'field-1': [u'value1'], u'field-2': [[u'value-2a', u'value-2b']]}
```

For that reason, form validation fails for `field-2` because `getlist` for that field returns list of lists (with one value) and not list of values.

Comment: This seems like it'd only be necessary if you're building forms dynamically and have no way of knowing what will be in the form when it's generated... in which case you should probably be either defining your fields in a way that includes your type. If that's not what you're doing, you may want to step back and rethink whether this is a good approach to whatever problem you're attempting to solve (and really, putting that in your question would allow for much more useful answers).

Comment: Could you please describe the expected `dict` you would like to convert this sample `POST` to?

Comment: @kungphu I don't think that converting `QueryDict` to `dict` without loosing `list` data is something unusual. Anyway, I re-edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a django QueryDict to Python Dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349573/how-to-change-a-django-querydict-to-python-dict)

Comment: That's not my point. It's just part of working with Django that inputs with multiple values require using `getList`; frankly, I don't like it that much, but it's how the framework handles that use case; realistically, your options are to use what the framework provides (often a good idea) or to subclass/override the classes/functions it provides (which is also sometimes a good solution). Which works for you depends entirely on your specific circumstances.

Comment: I've updated my question and divided it into two problems. Generally, the whole operation is simple: I just want to save form data to database (or file) and then create form from this data. It seems like common use-case but I have many troubles with this simple task, especially when form contains multi-value fields.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`lists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists). The format is compatible with the `dict` contructor.

```
post_data = dict(request.POST.lists())
```

Comment: Yes, but then all `dict` values will be lists. Of course, I can use `{k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in request.POST.lists()}` and it is answer to my question, however I thought it would be simpler.

Comment: The actual implementation of this functionality is the [MultiValueDict](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L48)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

`json.dumps(query_dict)`

might be what you are looking for. 
From [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Unfortunately `json.dumps(request.POST)` acts as `request.POST.dict()` and loses list values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add MultiValueDict along with QueryDict,

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict, MultiValueDict

dictionary = {'key_1': ['1'], 'key_2': ['1', '2'], }
query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
query_dict.update(MultiValueDict(dictionary))
```