# Can't extract list from QueryDict in Django?

Tags: python, django

Django 1.7
Python 2.7

I have a QueryDict object (let's name it `qd`):

```
<QueryDict: {u'org': [u''], u'songs': [u'1', u'2'], u'user': [u'222'], u'name': [u'test_name']}>
```

but I can't seem to get the 'songs' value.

I've tried:

```
qd.get('songs')
qd['songs']
qd.__getitem__('songs')
```

but they all return `u'2'` .

Why can't I get a list, it seems so trivial?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22100334/3297613

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.iterlists

Comment: ^ Not exactly a duplicate, you can use `qd.getlist('songs')` to get multiple values of a key in a QueryDict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to return the data as a list:

```
qd.getlist('songs')
```

Comment: ty, worked like a charm. didn't even know about getlist.