# List from key in Django QueryDict return one element instead of the whole list

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django and I am accessing `request.POST` from my view. The code is as follows:

```py
data = request.POST
print(data)
```

Which returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'name': ['Sam'], 'phone': ['+10795524594'], 'message': ['Es-sénia'], 'Coupon': [''], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['xcGnoJOtnAmXcUBXe01t7ItuMC8BAFHE
6H9Egqd8BuooxLbp3ZrqvwzTZAxukMJW', 'xcGnoJOtnAmXcUBXe01t7ItuMC8BAFHE6H9Egqd8BuooxLbp3Zrq``vwzTZAxukMJW'], 'Size': ['S', 'M']}>
```

But, whether using `.dict()` method or using `data.get("Size")`, I only get one element; not the whole list. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you be more clear ? What do you want ? The length ? the keys or values ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't extract list from QueryDict in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282016/cant-extract-list-from-querydict-in-django)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `data.getlist(key)`. It is a bit weird, see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Comment: Also you can read this thread where is explained why this happen: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130

Comment: @allexiusw Thanks I found the solution from the following thread! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282016/cant-extract-list-from-querydict-in-django
It was weird, not the kind of stuff you'de expect to happen