# How to pass a <select> in a View using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I was trying to make a cart system in Django and wanted to pass Size and the Quantity of product as `<Select>`

input in View.
My Template have :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
              Select Size:
              <select  name="sizes">
                {% for size in product.sizes.all %}
                <li class="list-item list-inline-item"><option value="{{size.nameSize}}">{{size.nameSize}}</option> </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>


          </ul>
```

This is how it looks :

[image: WebpageProduct]

But when i Submit it using the Add to Cart Button i get error:

[image: Error Part 1]
[image: Error Part 2]

This is the code in the view:

```
def add_item(request,pk):
product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
size = request.POST['sizes']
selectsize = Size.objects.get(nameSize=size)
user = request.user
usercart = Cart.objects.get(owner=user)
newitem = CartItems.objects.create(cart = usercart,product=product,size=selectsize) 
items = usercart.cartitems
return render(request,'cart.html',{'cartitems':items})
```

I am trying to use the name of the size from the Template and compare the size name i have in the database for that product Using:

```
selectsize = Size.objects.get(nameSize=size)
```

I was able to get size with name 36 so i wanted to pass the value 36 from the template to the variable size using post.

But i get the error mentioned which i believe is because name for the `<select>` is common in all the `<option>`.

If i can either get an alternate way to do that or solve this error both type of solutions are welcomed.
*I am not using Django Forms because i don't know how to have django form display like i am displaying my products in cart and on the product page.

**ANSWER**

> I was missing a submit button and was rather using a `<a href="{% url 'add_item' product.pk %}>Add To Cart</a>"` to submit the form which was not working.
>   Now i replaced it with `<button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 10px;" type="submit">Add To Cart New</button>`
>   And the form Action is given the link i was trying to go to.

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add_item' product.pk %}">
```

A silly mistake on my side.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what @Yevhenii M. said, and talking particularly about the `MultiValueDictKeyError`:

This error happens when the given key (`sizes` in this case) is not found in the POST dict. This might be happening (i'm only guessing, since you didn't post the full html code), because you didn't put the corresponding `<form>` tag surrounding the `select`.
So, the final code would look something like:

```
<form action="url-to-send-form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="sizes">
    {% for size in product.sizes.all %}
        <option value="{{size.nameSize}}">{{size.nameSize}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

The `{% csrf_token %}` is needed in order to protect you against Cross Site Request Forgery attacks (more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/)

---

**EDIT:** Now that I take a closer look, the error message shows that the url is being called with a GET request (maybe because of trying to access to */item_added/1* straight from the browser's url). That is why django can't find the `sizes` key.

One common way to call the url via post, is as shown in the code snipet above, and adding a submit button to the html:

```
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes that was the error ... i was using <a href ... to go to the submission page but that was not submitting the form. I worked on that i found that problem. Now i can see you also pointed out the same.  
`MultiValueDictKeyError` was there because the form was not getting submitted. @aleclara95 and @Yevhenii M. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to use `<ul>` tag here.

You can write:

```html
Select Size:
<select  name="sizes">
    {% for size in product.sizes.all %}
        <option value="{{size.nameSize}}">{{size.nameSize}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and result will be the same.

2. Since you didn't specify that `add_item(request, pk)` works only by POST, then you can't expect that request.POST always will be presented.

Better write your code as this:

```py
if request.POST:
    # do something
```

And if you don't specify default value for your select in template, then `sizes`will not be in your `request.POST`.
You can write like this just to be sure that you got some value:

```py
request.POST.get('sizes', 'some_default_value')
```

3. Just because you get `MultiValueDictKeyError` you need to see what you get in request. Maybe you get QueryDict, then you need to extract first value. For example, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349573/how-to-change-a-django-querydict-to-python-dict). For example, print your request.POST or check type.