# List column data in Django template can not be iterated

Tags: python, django

Please read my code

```
<p>{{request.POST}}</p>
<p>langchi : {{request.POST.langchi.0}}/{{request.POST.langchi.1}}/{{request.POST.langchi.2}}/{{request.POST.langchi.3}}<p>
<p>langeng : {{request.POST.langeng.0}}/{{request.POST.langeng.1}}/{{request.POST.langeng.2}}/{{request.POST.langeng.3}}</p>
<p>langjpn : {{request.POST.langjpn.0}}/{{request.POST.langjpn.1}}/{{request.POST.langjpn.2}}/{{request.POST.langjpn.3}}</p>
```

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laG7y.png)

We can tell in the request.Post, there are 3 list data langchi, langeng and langjpn.
But when I try to read them by request.Post.langchi.0,request.Post.langchi.1...
I can not get the actual value.
Did I do something wrong?

Appreciate for any help.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349573/how-to-change-a-django-querydict-to-python-dict) could help you. I would try to put those lists into the context through the view, but honestly I haven't faced this specific problem before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.